# How to convert SQL Query to Lambda Expression

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, lambda

Here is my SQL Query:

```
SELECT
  UserName,
  IsApproved
FROM aspnet_Users u
INNER JOIN aspnet_Membership m
  ON u.UserId = m.UserId
```

Can anybody help me how to write with lambda expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
from u in context.aspnet_Users 
join m in context.aspnet_Membership on u.UserId equals m.UserId select new { u.UserName, m.IsApproved};
```

Comment: If would be like this , how will be?                                                                          select UserName, IsApproved
from aspnet_Users u
inner join aspnet_Membership m on u.UserId = m.UserId
where u.UserName = @UserName

Comment: It will be, select u.UserName, m.IsApproved from aspnet_Users u inner join aspnet_Membership m on u.UserId = m.UserId where u.UserName = @UserName

Answer (score 1):

```
from u in aspnet_Users 
join m in aspnet_Membership on u.UserId equals m.UserId
select new { u.UserName, m.IsApproved };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `JOIN` with Lambda Expression something like this,

```
var result = aspnet_Users
                .Join(aspnet_Membership, 
                u => u.UserId, 
                m => m.UserId, 
                (u, m) => new
             {
                UserName = u.UserName,
                IsApproved = u.IsApproved
             }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

A what about this query:

select UserName, IsApproved
from aspnet_Users u
inner join aspnet_Membership m on u.UserId = m.UserId
where u.UserName = @UserName

Where to put "where" in this case? @UserName is the string parameter that i define in 
 public ActionResult UserActivation(string UserName)
{
...
}